# How to check if my token is active ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, token, access-token

I would like to set my token only once per user, do you know how to check if my token is already set ?

Here is my Controller :

```
def connexion
        code = request.params[:code]
        @decoded_code = URI.decode(code)

       @id_connection = request.params[:id_connection]

        @token = HTTParty.post('https://test-sandbox/auth/token/access', 
            body: {
                client_id: XXXXXX,
                client_secret: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
                code: @decoded_code
            }
        )
end
```

If I go back to my page and re-set the token I have the following error : You have already got an access_token for this user

Comment: There must be an `expires` attribute in the token object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||=` operator to set token, if it is not set than it will try to get token

```
        @token ||= HTTParty.post('https://test-sandbox/auth/token/access', 
            body: {
                client_id: XXXXXX,
                client_secret: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
                code: @decoded_code
            }
        )
```